# Prove that if $AB=0$ then the set of columns of $B$ is the subset of the set of solutions to $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Given matrices $A_{m \times n}, B_{n \times p}$ (these matrices are not zero matrices) prove that the set of $B$ columns is the subset of the set of solutions of the system $Ax=0$

If $AB=0$ then for every row of matrix $A$ and column of matrix $B$ we have:
$$
R^A_i \cdot C^B_j=0 \qquad 1 \le i \le m, \qquad 1 \le j \le p
$$

If we choose any column $C^B_j$ for $1\le j \le p$ then in particular:

$$
a_{11}b_{j1}+a_{12}b_{j2}+...+a_{1n}b_{jn}=0
$$
$$
a_{21}b_{j1}+a_{22}b_{j2}+...+a_{2n}b_{jn}=0
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
a_{m1}b_{j1}+a_{m2}b_{j2}+...+a_{mn}b_{jn}=0
$$

This seems too simple for a proof, not sure if this is correct.

Comment: I think you should swap the indices of your $b_{ji}$'s. But otherwise it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that for any two compatible matrices $A,B$, each column of $AB$ is $A$ times the corresponding column of $B$.

Comment: So is my proof good?

Comment: @Yos Yes, just point out explicitly that your calculations show exactly that $AC^B_j=0$, for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB=0$ then for all $i,j$, by the definition of matrix multiplication
$$
AB = \sum_ka_{ik} b_{kj}=0
$$
In particular for any given $j$, the set of $b_{kj}$ is $B_{*j}$, the $j$-th column of $B$.

And since the definition of matrix multiplication has 
$$
A B_{*j} = \sum_ka_{ik} [B_{*j}]_{kj}= \sum_ka_{ik} b_{kj}
$$
and we saw above that this is zero the proof is completed.

This is essentially the same as your proof, so you did fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof seems to be valid to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let ${v_1, v_2, ..., v_n}$ be the column vectors of B such that B=[${v_1}$ ${v_2}$ ... ${v_n}$]. Then 
AB= [${Av_1}$ ${Av_2}$ ... ${Av_n}$]. But by hypothesis, $AB=0$ implies ${Av_i} = 0$ for all $i=1,2,...,n$. Thus for each $i$, ${v_i}$ is a solution to $Ax=0$ and this completes the proof.